# How to get pitches from a wav buffer in JAVA - Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: java, signals

I am new to signal processing and am trying to detect the pitches in a wav file. I generated a 2-channel wav file that plays 3 distinct notes in 1 second. I was able to read the wave using a class a java and have a double array:

```
-0.12847900390625
-0.161651611328125
-0.161651611328125
-0.1907958984375
-0.1907958984375
-0.215179443359375
-0.215179443359375
       .
       .
       .
```

I was to get the notes that are being played in the double array. I have googled around and believe a Fast Fourier Transform is the way to go. However, I am a bit unsure what this Transformation does.

Does FFT return the frequency at a given time period?

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The Discrete Fourier Transform is used to map any discrete time-domain signal into frequency domain to reduce computation while performing operations like  convolution, co-relation etc since it is easier to compute in frequency domain and take the inverse transform and convert back into time domain compared to direct operation in time domain.
FFT is the simpler algorithmic implementation of DFT with reduced time complexity of  `O(nlogn)`compared to time complexity of DFT `O(n^2)`.

You can find more details here:

http://www.dspguide.com/ch12/2.htm